# Laravel 5 RESTful API - Understanding resource concepts

Tags: php, rest, laravel-5, restful-authentication, middleware

I am developing a RESTful API with Laravel 5. I have some resource in my `routes.php` file and everything works properly.

But now I had added `auth.basic` middleware and I want introduce the user roles and I got confused.

In my Controller I have a constructor to call 2 middleware, auth.basic and roles middleware, but cannot continue because of lack of knowledge.

What do I need? Well, I need to set the user roles who can access every controller, but cant achieve this. Im the Controller I would like to access the user to check his role and compare it with the role stablished on the Controller, but I don't know how to access the user, can you help me?

EDIT:

I put this on the constructor of the Controller

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    $actions = $request->route()->setAction( ['roles' => ['admin', 'seller', 'buyer']]);
    $this->middleware('auth.basic');
    $this->middleware('roles');
  }
```

Basically I inject the request in the controller constructor and then I set an action called roles.
Then I call middleware auth.basic to set the user.
And last call middleware roles which checks the user role against the roles array in the request, if it has the role or if he is root, then result is true, else I return error:

```
return response([
             'error' => [
             'code' => 'INSUFFICIENT_ROLE',
             'description' => 'You are not authorized to access this resource.'
         ]
         ], 401);
```

Now I have the error that always get:

```
{"error":{"code":"INSUFFICIENT_ROLE","description":"You are not authorized to access this resource."}}
```

Thats because User model dont returns a Role. See my class:

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    //Comprobacion del rol del usuario
    public function hasRole($roles)
    {
        $this->have_role = $this->getUserRole();
        // Check if the user is a root account
        if($this->have_role->name == 'root') {
            return true;
        }
        if(is_array($roles)){
            foreach($roles as $need_role){
                if($this->checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else{
            return $this->checkIfUserHasRole($roles);
        }
        return false;
    }
    private function getUserRole()
    {
        return $this->role()->getResults();
    }
    private function checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)
    {
        return (strtolower($need_role)==strtolower($this->have_role->name)) ? true : false;
    }

    //User relation with role

    public function role(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution!!!!! Thanks **Phorce** for guiding me, you gave me the idea basics. I post it here for everyone who needs. How to get Role Authentication for a RESTful API with Laravel 5.

Explanation. In the controller of the route I call a constructor for the middleware, first add the attribute roles (sets which roles can access this route) with an injected $request object. Then I call middleware auth.basic for requesting user, and then another middleware to check roles. Ando thats it! All working.

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckRole
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //return $next($request);

        // Get the required roles from the route
         $roles = $this->getRequiredRoleForRoute($request->route());
         // Check if a role is required for the route, and
         // if so, ensure that the user has that role.
         //print "HasRole:".$request->user()->hasRole($roles).".";
         if($request->user()->hasRole($roles) || !$roles)
         {
             return $next($request);
         }
         return response([
             'error' => [
             'code' => 'INSUFFICIENT_ROLE',
             'description' => 'You are not authorized to access this resource.'
         ]
         ], 401);
     }
     private function getRequiredRoleForRoute($route)
     {
         $actions = $route->getAction();
         //print "actinos:".print_r($actions);
         return isset($actions['roles']) ? $actions['roles'] : null;
     }
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email', 'password', 'role_id'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    protected $have_role;
    protected $profile;

    //Comprobacion del rol del usuario
    public function hasRole($roles)
    {
        $this->have_role = $this->getUserRole();
      //$this->have_role = $this->role()->getResults();
        // Check if the user is a root account
        if($this->have_role->nombre == 'root') {
            return true;
        }
        if(is_array($roles)){

            foreach($roles as $need_role){
                if($this->checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else{
            return $this->checkIfUserHasRole($roles);
        }
        return false;
    }
    private function getUserRole()
    {
        return $this->role()->getResults();
    }
    private function checkIfUserHasRole($need_role)
    {
      if($need_role === $this->have_role->nombre){
        return true;
      }else{
        return false;
      }
        //return (strtolower($need_role)==strtolower($this->have_role->name)) ? true : false;
    }

    //Relaciones de user

    public function role(){
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::resource('perfiles','PerfilesUsuariocontroller',[ 'only'=>['index','show'] ]);
```

Controller Constructor method

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
  {
    $actions = $request->route()->setAction( ['roles' => ['root', 'admin', 'seller']]);

    $this->middleware('auth.basic');
    $this->middleware('roles');
  }
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution - Apologies that I could not answer properly as I was at work and could not post.

Comment: Don't worry @Phorce, you guided me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I got the following:

How do I handle auth middleware...

Well, let's assume that you have two middlewares `auth.basic`, `auth.admin`

You can then have your routes be like:

```
Route::post('/api/getResponse', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    $var = "you have access to this route";
    return json_encode($var);
}]);
```

Here, you set whether or not, and, who has access to this particular route, in this case, only people that have admin rights would be able to access it.

If, for example, you do not have a middleware for "admin" you can create it by running the artisan command `php artisan make:middleware admin` and then you put your logic inside of the file that has been created. In this instance, the logic would check to see if the user (signed in) has admin rights.

EDIT:

As you pointed out in your reply:

> I dont user Route::post, I use Route::resource for handling RESTful API requests

You can therefore use a group, see:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('API_USER', 'API_USER_CONTROLLER');
});
```

This will then allow you to use your admin group as GROUP and therefore, all your routes that have access can go in here. In the past, I have just created separate groups for all of my user groups, i.e. `admin` would have it's own, `user` would have its own and `moderator` would have it's own. But, I believe you can use the following:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth|admin'], function()
{

}
```

This group reads: `should be open to auth users OR admin` but I have not fully tested this.

Comment: So instructive your answer, thanks. But the problem is that I have more than 1 user role (not only admin, also buyer and seller), and I dont user Route::post, I use Route::resource for handling RESTful API requests.

Comment: Well I think I am begining to understand the way to do it. Just begining. With route:group(['before]) I assume you are calling the auth middleware and the admin middleware, true? The | character acts as a Pipe? I mean, check auth and then check admin?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal Yes, this is true. Or, appears to be. In all honesty, I have not used this method using the pip personally, but I have come across it before. Does the method work?

Comment: I cannot make it work. But I had an idea, see my edit please.